# Hausdorff condition in "continuous image of a compact set is compact"

Tags: general-topology

In the book I'm following, compact spaces are also required to be Hausdorff by definition.

Then, is the following oft-cited statement true?

> *Continuous image of a compact space is compact.*

I guess not, and I think that we must adpat it to read:

> *Continuous image of a compact space in a Hausdorff space is comapct.*

Can you confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid confusion, let's use the term **quasi-compact** to mean "every open cover has a finite subcover", and avoid using "compact" altogether.

1. It is true that the continuous image of a quasi-compact set is quasi-compact.
2. It is not true that the continuous image of a quasi-compact Hausdorff space is Hausdorff. For example, let $X = \{ 0 , 1 \}$, let $\tau_{\text{dis}}$ be the discrete topology on $X$, and let $\tau_{\text{Sier}} = \{ \emptyset, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0 , 1\} \}$ be the **Sierpiński topology**. Then both $(X , \tau_{\text{dis}})$ and $(X , \tau_{\text{Sier}})$ are quasi-compact (because $X$ is finite) and $(X , \tau_{\text{dis}})$ is Hausdorff while $(X , \tau_{\text{Sier}})$ is not (since $0$ and $1$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets). Then the identity map $(X , \tau_{\text{dis}}) \to (X , \tau_{\text{Sier}})$ is continuous, since its domain is discrete, but its image is not Hausdorff.
3. It is true that every subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff, therefore if $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, $X$ is quasi-compact, and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then the image $f(X)$ is quasi-compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: Or you can replace the Sierpiński topology with the indiscrete topology... not sure why I made that more complicated than it had to be.

Comment: @Atom: You should be aware that most point-set topologists use the term *compact* to mean simply that every open cover has a finite subcover and do not use the term *quasi-compact* at all; I’d been a topologist for a good 40 years before I encountered it. It’s most common amongst algebraic geometers and those influenced by Bourbaki’s idiosyncratic usages.